# Wordpress Weird Serialization Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, serialization

So we've had this bizarre WP bug where rewrite rules aren't flushing properly in our Production environment only.  While debugging, I found this interesting issue I think might be the cause.

```
$serialized_value = maybe_serialize( $value, $option );

if ($option == 'rewrite_rules') {
    error_log(print_r($serialized_value,true));
}
```

Displays something different than,

```
$serialized_value = maybe_serialize( $value, $option );
if ($option == 'rewrite_rules') {
    print_r($serialized_value);
}
```

The error_log version is larger and the correct version.  The print_r is smaller, not as large and the incorrect version.  Here is the function in WP which serializes.

```
function maybe_serialize( $data, $option ) {
if ( is_array( $data ) || is_object( $data ) ) {
        $newdata = serialize( $data );
        return $newdata;

}

// Double serialization is required for backward compatibility.
// See https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12930
// Also the world will end. See WP 3.6.1.
if ( is_serialized( $data, false ) )
    return serialize( $data );

return $data;
}
```

Why would it display something differently?

Comment: all good.  Figured it out.  The rewrites were actually getting updated 3 times with 3 different values. The print_r was killing the process on the 1st time, the error_log had all 3 and I missed them.